# Spring Integration AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler doInit vs onInit

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, message-handlers

I am refactoring some code from Spring Integration 2.x to 4.x and have come across a compile error in a handler that extends `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler`.

The `onInit` method on that Abstract Class is `final`, yet my `legacy` code overrides it successfully in the 2.0 S.I. code.

There is a method that seems to be able to be over-ridden called

```
doInit()
```

What is the difference in use between the `onInit` method and the `doInit` method.  The java docs are not very helpful (as a matter of fact they contain no information except the `onInit` method is `final`.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right: there is no difference with those methods and they are just called from the `IntegrationObjectSupport#afterPropertiesSet()`.

The reason to make `onInit()` as `final` to protect implementation from the issue not invoking the `super.onInit()` in their implementation :-).

As you see `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler#onInit()` has critical code like:

```
this.advisedRequestHandler = (RequestHandler) proxyFactory.getProxy(this.beanClassLoader);
```

Comment: Please be sure to checkout the [migration guides](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki). This particular breaking change was [documented here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-2.2-to-3.0-Migration-Guide#abstractreplyproducingmessagehandler-oninit-method).

Comment: Thank you both.  I had read the 3.x to 4.x migration guide but had not read the 2.2 to 3.0 migration guide.